# How would I code this particular MIPS operator in C?

Tags: c

I'm creating a MIPS emulator using C, and I am trying to create the method for BEQ and BNE, however the actions are confusing me. Below are the actions that are performed in MIPS and then how I've interpreted them, which is apparently incorrect.

**BEQ if(rs==rt) pc+=offset*4**

```
//beq
            else if(opCodeType == 4)
            {
                if(registers[rsVariable] = registers[rtVariable])
                {
                    pc = pc + offset*4;
                }
            }
```

**BNE if(rs!=rt) pc+=offset*4**

```
//bne 
            else if(opCodeType == 5)
            {
                if(registers[rsVariable] != registers[rtVariable])
                {
                    pc = pc + offset*4;
                }
            }
```

All help is very much appreciated as this is the final piece to the puzzle!

Comment: `if(registers[rsVariable] = registers[rtVariable])` --> use double equals `==` to compare equality.

Comment: `if(registers[rsVariable] == registers[rtVariable])` change to this

Comment: Configure your compiler to warn you about basic errors. If it is GCC or Clang, use `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: Since MIPS is a fixed-size encoding, you can make `pc` a `uint32_t*` and avoid scaling the offset yourself.